# Can someone explain to me what "if let" statement is?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift. I've never coded in Swift. In fact all my coding has been websites; HTML, CSS, Javascript. I'm looking for a basic, dumbed down answer to "What does an `if let` statement do?" I know this may sound lame, but I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find it explained well enough; not even the Apple website.

Comment: An optional is a box that might hold a value.  If the box isn't empty (nil), the  `if let` statement opens that box and assigns the value inside the box to a variable of the type held by the optional.  If the box is empty, the block following the `if let` is skipped.

Comment: What part of the description from Apple's "The Swift Programming Language" book are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is this the exact portion of apple you read? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html

Comment: Can I point you to this part of the stack overflow documentation: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/247/optionals/913/unwrapping-an-optional#t=201609170525358457091 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`let x = y` declares a new constant x and initializes it to the value of y. `if let x = y` says "if y has a non-nil value to initialize with, then declare a new constant x initialized to that value".

So it's a shorthand for:

```
if y != nil {
    let x = y!
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if let` is what's known as optional binding. To understand it, you first have to understand optionals.

An optional is a variable that can either contain a value or nil.

You declare an optional variable using a question mark:

var a:Int?

Here is a bit of code using optional binding:

```
var string1: String?

if let string2 = string1 {
  print("string2 = \(string2)")
}
```

The "if let" expression says "if the expression on the right side of the equals sign is not nil, create a new constant string2, unwrap the optional, and put it's value in string2.

With the code above, nothing would be printed, because string1 contains nil.

However, with another line in between:

```
var string1: String?
string1 = "foo"
if let string2 = string1 {
  print("string2 = \(string2)")
}
```

Then the print statement would execute.

I suggest downloading Apple's Swift book and reading the introductory chapters.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I've figured it out, and didn't even know that Apple had a book for Swift. I was simply reading their stuff on the website. I've read through some of the chapters, and it definitely makes sense now. Again, thank you for your answers!

Comment: You should pick the answer that you think is the best and click the check-mark to accept it.